# Insert or Update to a table with no primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have inherited a table with basic data that essentially looks like this:

```
person_id   first   last   activity_date
----------------------------------------
98765       Dan     Jones  2018-06-15
12345       Mary    Smith  2018-07-04
12345       Mary    Smith  2018-07-04
21212       Erin    Mark   2018-08-11
```

The two major challenges are that:

1. It has no Primary Key, and
2. There can be duplicate rows

A vendor will provide a CSV with updated data on a regular basis, and I need to add it to this existing table. This introduces two more challenges:

1. The new file is not a complete replacement for the existing data in the table, and
2. The new file may overlap part of the existing data in the table.

For example:

```
person_id   first   last   activity_date
----------------------------------------
12345       Mary    Smith  2018-07-04
12345       Mary    Smith  2018-07-04
21212       Erin    Mark   2018-08-11
87878       Tom     Davis  2018-08-12
```

So the question becomes, **how can I update the table given all of these challenges?**

My instinct is to create a duplicate table, add the new data, then use a query to identify the overlaps and the gaps. The lack of an `EXCEPT` command in MySQL makes this a challenge. So does the fact that there can be duplicate rows.

Can anyone suggest the SQL I may need to identify the missing rows from the CSV that I need to insert into the database?

Comment: Fix your data so there is no duplicates.  There is no reason to propagate such a bad data model.

Comment: The duplicates are intentional. They’re occurrences of an event. I don’t control the source data, so adding a more precise time stamp isn’t possible either.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new duplicate table as you describe, adding an auto_increment id field as a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
    (id int auto_increment primary key,
     `person_id` int,
     `first` varchar(20),
     `last` varchar(20), 
     `activity_date` date)
```

Create a unique key on this:

```
alter table table2 add unique key (`person_id`, `first`, `last`, `activity_date`);
```

And then insert all your data, using `IGNORE` to skip all duplicate data:

```
insert ignore into table2 (`person_id`, `first`, `last`, `activity_date`)
select * from table1
```

When you get the CSV file from your vendor, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), again with the `IGNORE` option, and that will only import data from the CSV file that does not exist in the database.

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you. Then to get the data back into the main table, another `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: I would actually drop the main table and rename the duplicate table as the main table (after inserting all the data). It will almost certainly be more useful in the long run to have a main table with a primary key.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. The `IGNORE` will skip all duplicate data, but the duplicates are important. They are not mistakes, they are intentional and must be preserved.

Comment: I'm confused. In your question, you say you "need to identify the missing rows from the CSV that I need to insert into the database". If you want to keep the duplicates, surely you want to insert **all** the rows from the CSV into the database?

Comment: Yes. We get updated files weekly. I must insert them into the table, bearing in mind that there may be overlaps. That’s what makes the duplicate rows such a challenge.

Comment: If you have no keys in the table, duplicate rows will simply get inserted in the order they are encountered. So why is that an issue?